# TextBlock not aligning text correctly C#

Tags: c#, textblock

So I have a textblock that is receiving response text from a webclient

When I do this call in a browser I get nicely formatted responses

like this

[image]

but when I do this in code and push it into my textblock I get this (note that all the data is there just scrolled off of the screenshot)

[image]

Here is my textblock XAML

```
 <TextBlock xml:space="preserve"  Text="{Binding toolResponseText,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I was hoping the space preserve line would have fixed this but it didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `xml:space = preserve` is talking about whitespace within the XAML. It's not useful to you here.

The important point is that the browser is displaying it with a monospaced font, whereas you're using a variable-width font.

Try:

```
FontFamily="Consolas"
```

within your XAML. (If that font family doesn't change the appearance, find another one which does, and is still monospaced...)

Comment: Hmmm no it appears that still produces the same result

Comment: Changing the font to Courier New fixed the issue. Thanks sir!